# How to get success or failure notification Asynchronously sending Emails in C#?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I prepared an email notification using Asynchronously for my current C# project.

```
smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
```

But there is not such way to get the success or failure notification from this email. Can you please suggest a proper method for this. 
Here is the code below:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); 
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com"); 
mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com"); 
mail.Subject = "This is an email"; 
mail.Body = "this is the body content of the email."; 
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1"); //specify the mail server address 
object userState = mail; 
smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SmtpClient_OnCompleted); 
smtp.SendAsync( mail, userState );
```

Comment: How do you get success/failure notification in the synchronous method?  Doesn't it just throw an exception on failure?  I imagine this would do the same, no?  What have you tested?

Comment: MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
            mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

            mail.Subject = "This is an email";
            mail.Body = "this is the body content of the email.";

           SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1"); //specify the mail server address
           object userState = mail; 

            smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SmtpClient_OnCompleted);
            smtp.SendAsync( mail, userState );

Comment: 1) Code is a lot easier to read in the question body than in a comment.  2) That code doesn't call this method, which may explain why this method isn't working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the method signature for `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`, you'll see that it returns a `Task`. Now, if you look into the code, you'll can see that any exception will be caught and returned via that `Task` exposed by the method. If you want any exception to propagate, you'll have to await on the method call:

```
await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message)
```

This is what the [source code looks like](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/SmtpClient.cs,728):

```
[HostProtection(ExternalThreading = true)]
public Task SendMailAsync(MailMessage message)
{
    // Create a TaskCompletionSource to represent the operation
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    // Register a handler that will transfer completion results to the TCS Task
    SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
    handler = (sender, e) => HandleCompletion(tcs, e, handler);
    this.SendCompleted += handler;

    // Start the async operation.
    try { this.SendAsync(message, tcs); }
    catch
    {
        this.SendCompleted -= handler;
        throw;
    }

    // Return the task to represent the asynchronous operation
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And `HandleCompletion`:

```
private void HandleCompletion(TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs,
                              AsyncCompletedEventArgs e,
                              SendCompletedEventHandler handler)
{
    if (e.UserState == tcs)
    {
        try { this.SendCompleted -= handler; }
        finally
        {
            if (e.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(e.Error);
            else if (e.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The following code i used to send email 

smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SmtpClient_OnCompleted);
            smtp.SendAsync( mail, userState );

Comment: @AbhilashThomas `SendMailAsync` and `SendAsync` are different. The former uses the Task Asynchronous Pattern, while the latter uses the Event Asynchronous Pattern.